# Way to stop iOS simulator from rebooting with appium

Tags: ios-simulator, appium-ios

Is there way to stop iOS simulator from rebooting with appium? So every test simulator is rebooted. It takes a lot of time. I tries noReset option as true, but did not help. I have macmini with latest os (10.12.6) and latest appium (1.2.7), XCode (9.2). What can I do?

```
desired_caps = {
    'platformName': 'iOS',
    'platformVersion': '11.2',
    'deviceName': 'iPad Air',
    'browserName': "Safari",
    'nativeWebTap': True,
    'safariIgnoreFraudWarning': True,
    'showXcodeLog': True,
    'clearSystemFiles': True,
    'newCommandTimeout': 600,
    'wdaLocalPort': 8100,
    'launchTimeout': 120000,
    'wdaLaunchTimeout': 120000,
    'sessionOverride': True
}
```

Tried to add `noReset=True` and `fullReset=False` options but it did not change anything.

It seems like it's done on purpose and can not be disabled, unfortunatelly. I have rather not so fast computer, and restarting ios simulator takes a lot of time.

Comment: Could you provide your Desired Capabilities ?

Comment: @arulchristopher, I've updated my question.

Comment: Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sim Resetting
```

By default, this driver will create a new iOS simulator and run tests on it, deleting the simulator afterward.

If you specify a specific simulator using the udid capability, this driver will boot the specified simulator and shut it down afterwards.

If a udid is provided and the simulator is already running, this driver will leave it running after the test run.

In short, this driver tries to leave things as it found them.

You can use the noReset capability to adjust this behavior. Setting noReset to true will leave the simulator running at the end of a test session.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/appium-xcuitest-driver .   THIS MAY HELP YOU.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but adding udid and setting noReset to True and fullReset to False did not help. It still kills sim right before test. Actually it does not kill sim after test, but before. I did not found any info about that.

Comment: Hi, could you remove this cap 'safariIgnoreFraudWarning': True from your list and try it out. Because its updating the settings in sim every time, thats why its rebooting